# Sum of numbers from previous year month until this years month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Being a beginner, I'm having a hard time coding this particular scenario in SQL Server 2008

[image]

As you can see, 
The SUM column for July 2017 for example is equal to the following:
August to Dec 2016 + Jan to July 2017 = 4625

Similarly, the SUM column for August 2017 is equal to the following:
Sep to Dec 2016 + Jan to August 2017 = 4625

[image]

How can I automate this from month to month?

I appreciate any help I can get. Trying to code this in SQL Server 2008

Comment: This is far harder on 2008 that it is on 2012, as you don't have access to the `ROWS BETWEEN` clause when using `OVER`. Considering that 2008 is out of support, and we've almost hit the extended support end, have you considered update? Do you have the option?

Comment: Sadly I dont at the moment. We will be upgrading to 2014 soon but thats probably end of next year. Is there no way to do this in 2008?

Comment: No as easy as `SUM([Numbers]) OVER (ORDER BY YourDateColumn ASC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`

Comment: This is in 2008?

Comment: Nope, that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

Using this methodology to find the first day of the current month:

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

We can expan on it to get the first day, of the next month, a year ago... i.e. 11 months ago.

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(month,-11,getdate())), 0)
```

Then, we just need to use it in a where clause to limit your data...

```
declare @startDate = (select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(month,-11,getdate())), 0))
declare @endDate = getdate()

select sum(someColumn)
from someTable
where dateColumn between @startDate and @endDate
```

Since you didn't provide your actual data set, just some pivoted data, I'm not sure of your column and table names

Comment: Thanks, this returns the 2017 column 'Sum of numbers' to me. I need to get the SUM column

Comment: Ah you want a window function or in this case a correlated sub-query. What's the actual column names?

Comment: the column names are Year, Month & Number. Hope that helps, also I need the query to run in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want window functions.  Assuming your data is already summarized by month:

```
select t.*,
       sum(numbers) over (order by yyyymm rows between 11 preceding and current row) as prev_12_sum
from t;
```

If the data is not already summarized, you can put this in a `group by` as well:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       sum(sum(numbers)) over (order by year(date), month(date) rows between 11 preceding and current row) as prev_12_sum
from t
group by year(date), month(date)
order by min(date);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Can you modify this so that it will work in SQL Server 2008?